# How to automatically hide column based on row value, which is based on an if function from an opposing worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Please bear with me as I am self-taught and very new to VBA coding.

I need help with a code for a work project to automatically/dynamically hide a column based on a row value within that column. In my example, based on a Yes/No data validation list in an alternate worksheet, the current worksheet will update and return the same "Yes" or "No" value. If the answer is "No", I need that column to automatically disappear once the user has chosen that option from the Data validation list.

The data set is as follows:
The Yes/No result is on Row 3, in the column range `B:AR`.
The results of Row 3 are as a result of a transcode formula from another worksheet.

Bonus points if the coding is truly dynamic, in that was I to add rows above Row 3, the code would automatically move to Row 4.

I have scoured the google realms and most code either doesn't update or is strenuously slow. An example of several codes I have attempted are below:

```vb
Sub Hide_Columns_Containing_Value()

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("B3:AR3").Cells
        If c.Value = "No" Then
            c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**So this is what you need to Do:**

First Define a `Named Range` in the worksheet for the Rows you want to check `No` in. Benefit of `Named Range` is it is `Dynamic`, so if you add another row before 3rd row, it will dynamically move the Named Range to 4th Row.

**Like this:**

[image: Named Range]

**After Making the named range add this Code to the Worksheet you are on:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("roww")) Is Nothing Then

    For Each cel In Range("roww")
            If cel.Value = "No" Then Columns(cel.Column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Next

End If


End Sub
```

**-Second Code to be added below the First One.**

```
Sub hdd()    

For Each cel In Range("roww")
            If cel.Value = "No" Then Columns(cel.Column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Next

End Sub
```

**Make Sure code is on the Correct sheet to work:**

[image: Sheet]

This will be a complete Dynamic code.

Comment: Hi Mikku

Cheers for such a quick response mate, much appreciated! 

Have defined the name of the range to be "YNQ1", and included the following in the worksheet code, and unfortunately it still isn't working?

Okay I have no idea how to enclose a picture. 

Code is as follows:

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


If Not Intersect(Target, Range("YNQ1")) Is Nothing Then

    For Each cel In Range("YNQ1")
            If cel.Value = "No" Then Columns(cel.Column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Next

End If


End Sub

Comment: Might I mention that cell answers in row 3 are all transposed results from another worksheet, so unsure if the background formula is resulting in the "No" response not being recognised?

Comment: That Shouldn't be an Issue

Comment: Can you change one cells value in that Range to No

Comment: This code will work when one of the values in that range will change, that change will automatically trigger this Macro. and it will hide all the columns in that range with No as Value.

Comment: I have changed multiple cells to no through the back-end, but cannot do it manually due to being part of an array. When I change the cells to appear as No, it doesnt work...

Comment: Wait...I just did it on a cell thats not part of an array and that has worked. So the array is stopping the macro from running on the columns applicable?

Comment: That shouldn't be the Case, whenever in the Defined Range any value changes to `No` the code should work and hide the columns. Maybe you defined a different range. Your Range should be `$B$3:$AR$3`

Comment: The range seems to be working. If I remove a transcode array and manually input "Yes" or "No" into say B3 or even G3 the macro runs and the column is hidden. Otherwise, the macro doesn't seem to pick up on the worksheet change? Could this be because its based on an alternative worksheet change?

Comment: In this another Worksheet Change , do you have `Application.EnableEvents = False` ?

Comment: Looked through module, workbook, other worksheet and current worksheet codes, no  Application.EnableEvents = False that I can uncover

Comment: It doesnt make sense. I change the backend code to make the row result "n", it wont disappear. Once I change a non-array result to "no", both the column relevant to that cell and the columns relevant to the above "No" result will now disappear? 

Its almost as if the transcode array is hierarchical until it finds another result, for which it will then run it properly

Comment: A little bit more playing around, just changing any cell outside that array, regardless of answer, achieves the result. Alternatively, If I click into the cell that wont disappear, then press enter, it will then work? But not instantaneously once it registers a 'No'

Comment: @Pascawali ... I have added another code. You need to add that one below the `Worksheet_Change` Code, after that add this line before `End Sub` of the code that is printing your Array in this Sheet. `Call hdd` ..... This should complete the Job. Change the Range as you did in that code.

Answer (score 0):

Hope a little faster

```
Sub Hide_Columns_Containing_Value( _
        ByVal msg As String, _
        ByVal r As Range)

    Dim c As Range

    Set c = r.Find(msg)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then

        c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    End If
End Sub
```